# Swift: Implementing Protocol Initializer in a Class

Tags: swift, inheritance, swift-protocols

I am trying to understand why Swift enforces a class that conforms to a protocol with an initializer to be marked as required. This essentially enforces any subclasses to also implement that initializer. Surely the designated superclass initializer would be inherited?

The quotes below are taken from the Swift Language Guide:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID272

> You can implement a protocol initializer requirement on a conforming
>   class as either a designated initializer or a convenience initializer.
>   In both cases, you must mark the initializer implementation with the
>   required modifier:

```
class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
    required init(someParameter: Int) {
        // initializer implementation goes here
    }
}

class SomeSubclass: SomeClass {
    required init(someParameter: Int) { // enforced to implement init again
        // initializer implementation goes here
    }
}
```

> The use of the required modifier ensures that you provide an explicit
>   or inherited implementation of the initializer requirement on all
>   subclasses of the conforming class, such that they also conform to the
>   protocol.

**EDIT:**
I had not initially mentioned that I am currently limited to Swift 2.1. It appears to be a compiler issue in this release and does not occur in later versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Surely the designated superclass initializer would be inherited?

No, not always. If the subclass defines its own designated initialisers, then it won't automatically inherit the superclass' designated initialisers. Consider the following example:

```
class Foo {
    init() {}
}

class Bar : Foo {

    var str: String

    init(str: String) {
        self.str = str
    }
}

let b = Bar() // illegal – what value would the 'str' property have?
```

As `Bar` defines its own `init(str:)` designated initialiser, it doesn't automatically inherit `Foo`'s designated initialiser `init()`. This prevents unsafe initialisation in cases where the subclass declares its own stored properties.

Marking `init()` as `required` *enforces* `Bar` has an `init()`, be it through providing its own implementation:

```
class Foo {
    required init() {}
}

class Bar : Foo {

    var str: String

    init(str: String) {
        self.str = str
    }

    // implement required init(), as Bar defines its own designated initialiser.
    required init() {
        self.str = "foo" // now str is correctly initialised when calling init()
    }
}

let b = Bar() // now legal
```

Or by inheriting `Foo`'s implementation (when `Bar` doesn't define its own designated initialisers):

```
class Foo {
    required init() {}
}

class Bar : Foo {
    // inherits init() from Foo, as Bar doesn't define its own designed initialisers.
}

let b = Bar() // legal
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense for the reasoning to mark it as required. I guess what threw me off was the fact that in Swift 2.1, the compiler enforces you to implement the superclasses initializer even if the subclass has no designated initializers.

Comment: Marking this as accepted as it explains my question "Surely the designated superclass initializer would be inherited?".The original issue I was having was due to a Swift 2.1 limitation.

Answer (score 2):

You're not force to implement the initializer in the subclass. Consider this example, which compiles just fine:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    init(someParameter: Int)
}


class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
    required init(someParameter: Int) {
        // initializer implementation goes here
        print(someParameter)
    }
}


class SomeSubclass: SomeClass {
    // Notice that no inits are implemented here
}

_ = SomeClass(someParameter: 123)
_ = SomeSubclass(someParameter: 456)
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am currently limited to Swift 2.1 so could be a bug in that release. What version did you compile with?

Comment: Swift 3. Swift 2 is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for verifying the version. I understand it is deprecated but I am currently limited to its use due to circumstances outside of my control. Good to know its been addressed in later versions.