# Satisfying ExpressibleByArrayLiteral Protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

Why when I extend the ExpressibleByArrayLiteral protocol in swift I need to make the init required. In the definition of the protocol, the init method is just public.

I pretty much have the same thing as in the doc, https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral, and still, the compiler complains about making this `init(arrayLiteral: Element...)` required. The only difference I have is that I am implementing it in a class no a struct. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

Here is an implementation of my code:

```
public class Stack<T> {
private var buffer: [T]

init() {
    self.buffer = []
}

public func push(_ value: T) {
    self.buffer.append(value)
} 

public func pop() -> T? {
    return self.buffer.popLast()
}

var size: Int {
    return self.buffer.count
}

var isEmpty: Bool {
    return self.size == 0
}
} 

extension Stack: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
    init(arrayLiteral: T...) {
        for item in arrayLiteral {
            self.push(item)
        }
    }
}
```

The errors I am getting are:

1) designated initializer cannot be declared in an extension of 'Stack'; did you mean this to be a convenience initializer?

2) initializer 'init(arrayLiteral:)' must be declared public because it matches a requirement in public protocol 'ExpressibleByArrayLiteral'

3) initializer requirement 'init(arrayLiteral:)' can only be satisfied by a `required` initializer in the definition of non-final class 'Stack'

**Questions**:

**For error #1 ->** Why can't I declare a designated init in an extension?

**For error #2 ->** I understand this part, the protocol defines this as public. But why does the docs implement it with out the public keyword?

**For error #3 ->** This is pretty much my biggest question, why this needs to be required.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Related: [Swift: Implementing Protocol Initializer in a Class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42397348/2976878). You need to implement an initialiser requirement with a `required` initialiser in order to ensure that it's available to call on all potential subclasses.

Comment: my guess: you have more than one init, but the compiler needs to know, which is the required on.

Comment: When you say "I pretty much have the same thing," it's unclear what you mean there. The code you're referencing is not "extend the ExpressibleByArrayLiteral protocol." It's extending `OrderedSet` to conform to that protocol, which is completely different. Why don't you post the code in question and what you'd like it to do. (I'm pretty certain I know what you're problem is, but it's difficult to discuss while having to guess about the code.)

Comment: I will just re-emphasize that because `required` is a signal that the initializer must be available to all subclasses, structs and final classes don't need to mark as `required` because, due to the impossibility of having subclasses, there is no risk of `init` not being available to a subclass.

Comment: @RobNapier I just added more details. Let me know anything, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is inheritance: any `init` inside a protocol must be marked as `required` if adopted by a class. A `struct` cannot be inherited.

For a class, An `init` must initialize an instance of that same class or return `nil`. When that class adopts a protocol, itself and all its subclasses must provide their own implementations so the compiler can verify that fact:

```
class ClassA : ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
    required init(arrayLiteral elements: Self.Element...) {
        // this implicitly returns an instance of ClassA
    }
}

class ClassB : ClassA {
   // without its own init(arrayLitteral:), it will fallback on ClassA's init and return
   // an instance of ClassA, which Swift does not allow.
}
```

This is due to Swift's static typing system. Unlike in Objective-C where you think you create an `NSString` but actually get an `_NSContiguousString` instead (the so-called [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html) design pattern)

```
NSString * str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello world"];
// surprise: you may get an _NSContiguousString instead
```

---

Just get rid of the extension and implement it in the class's definition:

```
public class Stack<T> : ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
    private var buffer: [T]

    init() {
        self.buffer = []
    }

    public func push(_ value: T) {
        self.buffer.append(value)
    } 

    public func pop() -> T? {
        return self.buffer.popLast()
    }

    var size: Int {
        return self.buffer.count
    }

    var isEmpty: Bool {
        return self.size == 0
    }

    // MARK: -
    required public init(arrayLiteral: T...) {
        self.buffer = []
        for item in arrayLiteral {
            self.push(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify: In the general case of `required` initialisers, subclasses *can* inherit their superclass' implementation of the initialiser if that subclass doesn't define its own designated initialisers (and that inherited implementation will return a subclass instance just fine if called on the subclass). It's only in this *specific* case of `init(arrayLiteral:)` where the superclass' implementation cannot be inherited, as it has a variadic parameter.

Comment: Is it possible to elegantly extend ExpressibleByArrayLiteral in an extension? I just updated my question with more details, can you please check?

Answer (score 2):

> For error #1 -> Why can't I declare a designated init in an extension?

Because convenience initializers *must* call a designated initializer. Extensions may be defined in other files. With your current structure, it is possible for the class to have no designated initializer defined in this compile unit (file), and that creates too much confusion for the current compiler. (It's not that this is an unsolvable type-theory problem; it just creates problems when it needs to figure out everything within a single file.) Extensions are *extensions*. If they fundamentally change how the object works (like creating designated initializers), then they may not be able to be extensions.

> For error #2 -> I understand this part, the protocol defines this as public. But why does the docs implement it with out the public keyword?

Because the doc renderer always strips the `public` on protocols. If this is causing confusion, open a bug to bugs.swift.org.

> For error #3 -> This is pretty much my biggest question, why this needs to be required.

Because this is a non-final class. Consider if there were a subclass to `Stack` that had its own required initializer. How would you ensure that `init(arrayLiteral:)` called it? It *couldn't* call it (because it wouldn't know that it existed). So either `init(arrayLiteral:)` has to be `required` (which means it needs to be part of the main declaration and not a extension), or `Stack` has to be `final`.

If you mark it `final`, this works like you expect. If you want it to be subclassed, just move it out of the extension and into the main body, and define it like this:

```
public convenience required init(arrayLiteral: T...) {
    self.init()
    for item in arrayLiteral {
        self.push(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!